# Cornerstone compare file in wrong line

Tags: cornerstone

I check the file change in the cornerstone 3(version 3.0.1(22,575))
It seems the basic function of compare file with ridiculous result. I got the right result when use the Kaleidoscope instead.

How can I fix the internal file compare tools ?
 Is it a really difficult science for the software to deal with ?
[Cornerstone 3 compare result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10SeB.png)
[Kaleidoscaope compare result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lqRV.png)

Comment: I have same problem

Comment: I have same problem, not only v3 but also v2.7.18